# Select entire line from text file with quotations in the line using ADODB in VBScript

Tags: sql, scripting, vbscript, adodb

I have a rather large text file that has some duplicate lines. The duplicates are not right after each other. I would like to get a unique set of the lines.

Here is the code I am currently using and seems to work pretty well except I cannot SELECT the entire line due to some quotations in each line.

```
Const adOpenStatic = 3
Const adLockOptimistic = 3
Const adCmdText = &H0001

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strPathToTextFile = "C:\Documents and Settings\"
strFile = "DuplicateLines.txt"

objConnection.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
      "Data Source=" & strPathtoTextFile & ";" & _
          "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""

objRecordSet.Open "Select DISTINCT * FROM " & strFile, _
    objConnection, adOpenStatic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText

Do Until objRecordSet.EOF
    WScript.Echo objRecordSet.Fields.Item(0).Value   
    objRecordSet.MoveNext
Loop
```

My text file looks a little something like this:

```
DELETE user WITH user_name="TestName" id="123" type="admin"
DELETE user WITH user_name="SecondName" id="456" type="user"
DELETE user WITH user_name="TestName" id="123" type="admin"
DELETE user WITH user_name="TestName" id="123" type="admin"
```

My Select statement is only returning the following:

```
DELETE user WITH user_name=
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, the problem is caused by the " (used as default delimiter for text fields). A sure way to solve the problem is to put a schema.ini file in the strPathToTextFile folder:

```
[<strFile>]
ColNameHeader=False
Format=Delimited(;)
TextDelimiter=%
Col1=Line Char Width 500
```

and to remove the redundant/wrong info from the connection string:

```
... "Extended Properties=""text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited"""
==>
... "Extended Properties=""text;"""
```

Make sure to pick characters not used in your data and to set the Width for your one and only column sufficiently. After this i got:

```
DELETE user WITH user_name="SecondName" id="456" type="user"
DELETE user WITH user_name="TestName" id="123" type="admin"
```

Comment: this worked perfectly for me except that I needed to leave the `Extended Properties=""text;"""` in the connection string

Comment: @robbie: I edited the section about the connection string to avoid misunderstandings. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is marked as an ADODB / SQL question, but, the exercise can be solved easier via other means, i.e. if you use the `Scripting.FileSystemObject` and `Scripting.Dictionary` objects you can implement a more elegant solution:

```
Option Explicit

Const ForReading = 1

Dim objFSO, objFile, objDict, strFile, strLine

strFile = "DuplicateLines.txt"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strFile, ForReading)
While not objFile.AtEndOfStream
  strLine = objFile.ReadLine
  If Not objDict.Exists(strLine) Then
    Wscript.Echo strLine
    objDict.add strLine, 1
  End If
Wend
```